# Redis DECR entire group of keys

Tags: redis

Suppose I have a separate counter for thousands of clients (stored in redis), all using the same namespace. i.e. `client.counter.<client_id>`. I want to decrement all entries in that namespace by 1 (without going below zero). Is it possible to do this without iterating through every redis key? Is there a better way to handle this sort of data model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways.

> HASH solution

You can use [HASH](http://redis.io/commands#hash) to store the data, with the *namespace* as key,  *client_id* as field, and the *counter* as value.

```
// insert
hset client.counter client_1 1
hset client.counter client_2 2
...
hset client.counter client_N N

// get all client ids
hkeys client.counter

// decr the counter for each client
hincrby client.counter client_1 -1
```

If there are too many client, `hkeys` might block other operations to Redis. In this case, you can use `hscan` to incrementally iterate all client in the HASH.

> LIST solution

You can have a [LIST](http://redis.io/commands#list) to save all clients. When you want to decr the counter for all clients in the 'namespace', you just iterate the LIST to get the client ids, and then decr the corresponding counter one-by-one.

```
// insert client and id
set client.counter.client_1 1

// update the id list
lpush client.ids client_1

// get all client ids
lrange client.ids 0 -1

// decr the counter
decr client.ids.client_1
```

If there're too many clients, you don't need get all ids at one time. Also, you can use a [SET](http://redis.io/commands#set) the store the client ids.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update thousands of separate counters, you'll always have to traverse them one by one somehow.

You should look into the [`BITFIELD` command](http://redis.io/commands/bitfield) that's available as of version 3.2. With it, you can store all of your counters in a densely-packed array of counters under a single key. The nice thing about this is that if you want to increment all of the counters, a Lua loop would be an extremely efficient way to do it.